# How to delete \ (backslash) from string swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, string, encoding

I have a problem with backslash in strings.

When i create a string with this code:

```
 let url = webProtocol + siteHost + "/tables/coupon?$expand=source&$filter=Source/Name eq '" + category + "'&" + siteApi
```

I expect this URL

```
https://swoup.azurewebsites.net/tables/coupon?$expand=source&$filter=Source/Name eq 'Recommended'&ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
```

But I get this

```
https://swoup.azurewebsites.net/tables/coupon?$expand=source&$filter=Source/Name eq \'Recommended\'&?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
```

I tried to delete them using

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "")
```

But it doesn't help. Also I tried to add backslash before the **'** but it doesn't help.

Comment: Why do you have spaces in the URL you expect?

Comment: Have you encoded the url?

Comment: Supply a complete question,`webProtocol`, `siteHost`, `category` and`siteApi` are undefined. Provide a [mcve] with emphasis on complete.

Comment: As Aaron pointed out, the URL you are attempting to create is invalid, spaces and some other characters you use are invalid. Check here for valid characters in a URL -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid

Comment: Where/how do you you log the URL? Many tools display an escaped version and add backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSURLComponents and NSURLQueryItem to build URLs, not string concatenation.

```
let components = NSURLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "swoup.azurewebsites.net"
components.path = "/tables/coupon"
let category = "Recommended"
let expand = NSURLQueryItem(name: "expand", value: "source")
let filter = NSURLQueryItem(name: "filter", value: "Source/Name eq '\(category)'")
let api = NSURLQueryItem(name:"ZUMO-API-VERSION", value:"2.0.0")
components.queryItems = [expand, filter, api]
```

Gives you this URL from `components.URL`:

`https://swoup.azurewebsites.net/tables/coupon?expand=source&filter=Source/Name%20eq%20\'Recommended\'&ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear based on your question, but I believe the backslashes are not actually in the string, but being printed by XCode. For example, enter the following into a playground:

```
let siteApi="test=123"
let category="Category1"
let webProtocol="https://"
let siteHost="www.testme.com"
let url = webProtocol + siteHost + "/tables/coupon?$expand=source&$filter=Source/Name eq '" + category + "'&" + siteApi
print( url)
```

And you will see the output does not contain backslashes.

```
https://www.testme.com/tables/coupon?$expand=source&$filter=Source/Name eq 'Category1'&test=123
```

Comment: You aren't using back slashes,  in his code category is being filled in with `\'` and `\'` is special code in strings to mean single apostrophe.  The issue comes down do whatever is filling in category has to be doing `\\\'`

Comment: It's super confusing. It's an incomplete example and mixing quotes makes it tough to read. Hopefully he'll post the full code and we can have a better idea of where the problem is.

Comment: indeed it is confusing

Comment: Look at the placement of the backslashes, it's prior to the first single quote so I don't believe the issue is the contents of the category variable.

Comment: I thought that `'` alone is invalid in string literals and needed to be `\'`

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the variables that are not shown.

With this example complete (?) code example:

```
let webProtocol = "https://"
let siteHost = "swoup.azurewebsites.net"
let category = "Recommended"
let siteApi = "ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0"
let url = webProtocol + siteHost + "/tables/coupon?$expand=source&$filter=Source/Name eq '" + category + "'&" + siteApi
print (url)
```

Output
`https://swoup.azurewebsites.net/tables/coupon?$expand=source&$filter=Source/Name eq 'Recommended'&ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0`

There is no `\`.